# Trying to web-scrape through hundrededs of thousands of pdfs on government website. Want to do it as fast as possible

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, coding-efficiency

I'm trying to search through the U.S. technical manuals for anything relating to levees and flooding events. I think there are about 400,000 files hosted by them, and I'm trying to write code to download any of the pdf files that relate to what i'm studying.

The code I have works, it just takes 2 minutes for a single file. I'll be throwing this into a loop once I get this to work well which I assume will add even more time.

```
import requests
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a125775.pdf'

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

result = response.text

result1 = result.find('{{vm.optionsDisplay(vm.model)}}" value="0') 

if result1 == -1:

    print("sucks to suck")

else:

    with open("python.pdf","wb") as pdf: 

        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 

            if chunk: 

                pdf.write(chunk)
```

Again the code works for this file... but I can't figure out how to speed up the process.

Comment: Maybe you can look at `multiprocessing` module or `asyncio`

Comment: Maybe you could stream the file so you don't have to download all of it at once. Check [this](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests) out. You could do this on different processes to speed it up even more.

Answer (score 1):

If the [linked file](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a125775.pdf) is anything to go by, I think the scale of this task might be quite difficult.

This file is 9.6MB, so if it is an accurate representation of the 400,000 files then we would be downloading and saving 9.6*400,000=3,840,00MB (3.8 TB)

If we get a decent download speed of 1 MB/s this would take 1,066 hours (44 days).  This is assuming we are not limited by the US Govt servers (which they might if they see our IP trying to download 1TB+)

Also an interesting philosophical question is if it takes a computer 44 days to transfer the information from the database to it's memory I would wonder how long it would take a human to complete a similar process.

You could try and cut the number down by filtering files within the last 20 years or so.

Comment: The download is not a problem. I'm not expecting to download more than like 2-300 documents. The search function verifies that the document is even relevant before downloading. The problem is more the actual opening and searching of the document because it takes so long.